# Want to Create a Disk Partition

Tags: disk, partitioning, disk-management

Just switched full to the Ubuntu OS from the windows OS and I want to create disk partitions.

Can anyone teach me how to do that? 
Would anybody recommend that I do that? Also is it best to use the full disk not partitioned, and why?

Would there be future problems if I do not create partitions?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It is not clear what you want to do and why. If you have already installed Ubuntu, you not need to worry about partitions. To use a full disk, you have to have a single partition that spans the whole disk. Ubuntu installation has done that for you. That is the default. It won't create any future problem.

Comment: I suggest you search on YouTube for ”Gparted”. There are lots of examples. Have you already installed Ubuntu? If not the installer will do it for you. If you have installed Ubuntu you can install Gparted (if it’s not there already) and partition another disk. If you want to change the partitions on the disk where Ubuntu lives you will need a live disk/usb of Gparted to do that. Some people like to have a small partition for the system and another partition for home. It does mean you can reinstall the system with less risk to your data

Comment: I would advise, as the other commenters: don't trouble yourself with partitioning schemes, specially if you don't know what for. Let the Ubuntu installer do its thing, you will have a functioning system without any problems.

Comment: Only very rare configurations will work without partitions, and Ubuntu's installer makes partitions for you as needed. Since a lot of folks here have XY problems (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/254343 ), may we ask you to click [edit] and enhance your question to explain _why_ you want to partition your disk(s) further and what you believe it will do for you? Please feel free to provide web links to URLs of other web sites which discussed partitioning and led you to want to do so. Please don't use Add Comment; instead, click [edit].

Answer (score 0):

you should install gparted "sudo apt install gparted" or install from the softwarecenter then you can follow the ubuntu help page on creating disk partitions at this link 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/CreatingPartitions